# cannot compare password with bcrypt compare

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bcrypt

Im trying to build a node api for change password,

User must type the currentPassword and the new password

when bcrypt.compare the new currentPassword with the stored on db, i got always false, whatever it's wrong or correct

```
const changePass = async (req, res, next) => {


//email and password
const CurrentPassword = req.body.currPassword
let password1 = ''+req.body.password1
let password2 = ''+req.body.password2

const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password1, 10); 

let id = "" + req.body.id

User.findById( id )
    .then(user => {
        bcrypt.compare(CurrentPassword, user.password, (err, data) => {

            if (err) throw err

            if (data) {

                User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {password : hashedPassword    }, {new: false}, (err) => {
                if (err) throw err
            })

            } else {
                return res.status(401).json({ msg: "Invalid" })
            }

        })

    })

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to learn bcrypt I recommend you to visit  [bcrypt NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) because it will save you too much time later,

in your case I made some modification on your code  in order to check for the current password `OLD` and then compare between the `newPassword1` and the confirmation `passwordConfirmation`

feel free to use `console.log('')` when you have doubts about anything it will give you a good vision about your code status

```
const changePassword = async (req, res, next) => {
let id = req.body.nid;
if(id){
    console.log('Im here')
    const old = req.body.old;
    const newP = req.body.newP;
    const newP2 = req.body.newP2;

    User.findById(id,(err,user)=>{
        if(user){
            console.log(user)
            const hash = user.password;
            bcrypt.compare(old,hash,function (err,res){
                if(res){
                    if(newP === newP2){
                        bcrypt.hash(newP,10, (err,hash)=>{
                            user.password = hash;
                            user.save( (err,user) =>{
                                if(err) return console.error(err);
                                console.log(user.userName +' your password has been changed');

                            });
                        });

                    };
                };
            });
        }

    })
  }
}
```